# Chebishev’s and Markov’s inequalities and convergence a.s.

Tags: convergence-divergence, almost-everywhere

Let ${X_n}$ be a sequence of  i.i.d random variables with mean = 1 and variance $\sigma^2 =3$.
Show if the following converges almost surely:
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum^n X_i \longmapsto 1
$$

**Chebyshev Inequality**:

$$
\mathcal{P}(|\sum^n X_i - 1| > \epsilon*n)
\!
\begin{aligned}[t]
& \leq \frac{1}{n^2*\epsilon^2}* V(\sum^n X_i) \\
& = \frac{n*3}{n^2*\epsilon^2} \\
& = \frac{3}{n*\epsilon^2} \\
& = \frac{3}{\epsilon^2}\sum \frac{1}{n} = \infty
\end{aligned}
$$

Therefore for Borel Cantelli Lemma, there's no convergence almost surely.

However, using **Markov's inequality**:
$$
\mathcal{P}(|\sum^n X_i| > \epsilon*n)
\!
\begin{aligned}[t]
& \leq \frac{1}{n*\epsilon}* E(\sum^n X_i) \\
& = \frac{n}{n*\epsilon} \\
& = \frac{1}{\epsilon} \\
& = \sum \frac{1}{\epsilon} < \infty
\end{aligned}
$$

In this case, using Markov and BCT, there's the convergence almost surely.

May someone spot any mistake or more specifically, explain to me why should I use Chebyshev or Markov and why they give me different results?

Comment: Every real number is $\leq \infty$.

Comment: Related to which step?

Comment: The first step makes no sense at all.

Comment: There should be a typo, the convergence should be at 1.

Comment: I fixed the typo @geetha290krm

Comment: And the convergence of the sample mean to the distribution mean is a result of the laws of large numbers, so in probability and almost surely.

Comment: Why do I get different results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both your approaches look peculiar.  I would have thought you wanted to say:

- $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i$ has mean $n$ and variance $3n$
- so  $\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i$ has mean $1$ and variance $\frac{3}{n}$,
- with the result that Chebyshev's inequality would give: $$\mathbb P\left(\left|\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i - n\right|>n\epsilon\right)=\mathbb P\left(\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i - 1\right|>\epsilon\right) < \frac3{n\epsilon^2}$$ and $\frac3{n\epsilon^2} \to 0$ as $n$ increases, so you get convergence *in probability* of the sample mean to the population mean, equivalent to the weak law of large numbers.

This does not give the strong law of large numbers (convergence *almost surely*)  since $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty  \frac3{n\epsilon^2}$ is not finite.  Instead you need a more sophisticated approach such as [this](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/06/18/the-strong-law-of-large-numbers/) or [this](https://people.math.umass.edu/%7Eyaoli/ptrl.pdf) or [this](https://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/%7Ewinkel/bs3a07l9-10.pdf).

Comment: Thank you, everything’s clear. Why can’t I use Markov’s inequality?

Comment: Markov's inequality would require $X_i\ge 0$ and would give you $\mathbb P\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i -1 \gt \epsilon\right) < \frac{1}{1+\epsilon}$ which is not particularly helpful

Comment: But he used the absolute value for the markov's Inequality. Is that possible? If yes, the $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+\epsilon} < \infty$.

Comment: @Gabriele: we do not know the mean of $|X_i|$ or $|X_i-1|$ or $|\bar X-1|$ though perhaps we could bound them using the standard deviation.  Meanwhile, summing a positive constant infinitely often will give an infinite result

Comment: Clear. So therefore I should bound it by the $\mathcal{P} (\sum (|X_i - 1|^2))$ which gives me a result similar to Chebyshev and therefore no conclusion can be made?

Comment: @Gabriele. Yess - and this is the common way of proving Chebyshev's inequality from Markov's inequality

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct Chebyshev inequality would be $$\mathcal{P}\left(\left\vert \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}X_{i} -1\right\vert>\varepsilon \right)=\mathcal{P}\left(\left\vert \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} (X_{i}-1)\right\vert>n\varepsilon  \right)\leq \frac{1}{n^{2}\varepsilon^{2}}V\left( \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(X_{i} -1) \right)\\=\frac{3n}{n^{2}\varepsilon^{2}}=\frac{3}{n\varepsilon^{2}}$$
and hence $\frac{3}{n\varepsilon^{2}}\rightarrow 0$ as $n \to \infty$.